# Anybody implement saml 2.0 service provider with opensaml 2.5.1

Tags: java, cas, opensaml

I have to implement saml 2.0 on a code base that has opensaml 2.5.1 (older version of cas) and unfortunately cannot make use of the spring saml security extension (which uses a new version of newer opensaml). I have looked at how the spring extension handles the authorization request/response and have reversed engineered it to some extent. I am able to make the call from sp to the idp (sso circle) and attempt login, however I get a 500 error upon submit: Reason: Unable to do Single Sign On or Federation.

Is there any sample java opensaml 2.5.1 code that might shed some light on what I am doing wrong? Or are there other suggestions/ideas I am overlooking?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the AssertionConsumerService url I was sending in the request, was slightly different than the AssertionConsumerService value in my metatada (sp.xml) and hence was causing 500 errors